# Delete key doesn't work in vim insert mode

Tags: iterm, vi

I am using vim on a Mac in iterm2 and an external Windows style keyboard.

I would like to use the <kbd>Del</kbd> key to forward delete like it normally would on a text editor. However, when I press the <kbd>Del</kbd> key nothing happens and I need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> for it to forward delete.

I'm not sure if this is caused by vim or iterm.